# mySQL get highest ID odd results

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

Hey all i am getting an odd returned value in VB.net when i try to find the highest ID number in my table:

This is my VB.net code:

```
    objConn = New MySqlConnection(product.strConnString)
    objConn.Open()

    strSQL = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM product;"

    Try
        objCmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
        dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

        While dtReader.Read()
            nextDBID = dtReader(0)
        End While

        objConn.Close()
        objConn = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("LoadProduct: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

When i check the value of **nextDBID** it comes up as **39**. However, there is no 39 in the database!

When i run that exact query in mySQL GUI i get this:

```
select MAX(id) from fivestar_range.product;

37
```

My id data field is this in the product table:

```
37
10
11
12
7
8
6
5
4
3
2
1
13
14
36
21
```

I even tried using this query:

```
SELECT id FROM product ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And i still end up with **39** in the VB.net but still **37** in mySQL GUI.

What's going on that i'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your connection strings. You are likely looking at two different databases.

Comment: I stand corrected.. it was pointing at the wrong DB in mySQL GUI. Ugg.. thanks :o)